# Assembly language that corresponds to machine instruction in MIPS

Tags: assembly, binary, mips

I am working on a problem that asks for the assembly language that would correspond to the following machine instruction in MIPS:

```
OX3062FF80
```

Here is what I've done:

```
step 1: convert to binary

0011 0000 0110 0010 1111 1111 1000 0000

opcode: 000000 <--- im not sure about this part ( I thought it should always be zero)
rs: 00011
rt: 00010
rd: 11111
shamt: 11110
funct: 000000

add $15, $3, $2
```

Is this correct? I am going off an example but I am not entirely sure if its correct. Any help, advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a bitwise and immediate AND.

You had the first two steps right:

```
OX3062FF80
0011 0000 0110 0010 1111 1111 1000 0000
```

But not the rest.

First separate out the opcode, starting from the left.  All opcodes are 6 bits.

So the opcode in binary, from the left, is:

```
001100
```

which is 0xC.  [This is an andi instruction](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Instruction_Formats#Opcodes).

Then you need to separate out the fields according to the [MIPS I instruction format](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Instruction_Formats#I_Format);

```
001100  00011  00010  1111 1111 1000 0000 

opcode    rs    rt        immediate

Opcode:     0xC
rs:         0x03
rt:         0x02
Immediate:  0xFF80
```

I wrote some code and checked that an adi instruction has the above format in a disassembly listing.

To convert this into a assembly instruction:

The assembly language format of an andi is:

```
andi,rs,rt,IMM
```

Looking up the [MIPS registers](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~mssz/CompOrg/Table2.1-MIPSregisters.gif) for the rs and rt fields:

```
rs = 0x03 => $v1
rt = 0x02 => $v0
```

so the corresponding assembly instruction is:

andi  $v1,$v0,0xFF80

Comment: I understand up to where you explained. The answer would then be `andi $2, $3, (immediate?)`?

Comment: @user655321 except you should convert the numeric register values to their mnemonics.  I added that step.